# To create sub menu and subsub menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I've added custom menus to the admin menu.**I want to create subsub menu.**
my code is

```
add_menu_page('File_uploader', 'File uploader', '', 'file_uploader', 'file_uploader');
add_submenu_page('file_uploader', 'Templates', 'Templates', 'edit_pages', 'fileuploader_templates', 'fileuploader_templates');
```

I want `subsubmenu` under the `submenu` Template

Answer (score 0):

WordPress does not uses three level menus in administration - this approach to admin menus of your plugin would be out of the concept. Consider using just Top and Sub level pages, otherwise you'll have to modify admin menu walker (if there's any) and write down your custom functions for adding subsubmenu...